# 502 bad gateway error

Tags: mysql, magento, nginx, php

When I browse the Magento web site multiple times, I usually get 502 bad gateway error at Nginx.
Please help me on fixing this issue.

Note:- php5-fpm is not running some of the time. After restarting the php5-fpm, everything  is working fine but after some time I am getting the same`(php5-fpm is not running)` error again .

[image]

Ngnix Error Logs: -

```
2014/06/30 12:24:17 [error] 13359#0: *297122 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxxxxxxx, server: www.xxxxxxxx.com, request: "GET /ultimate-comics-x-men-1967641 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.xxxxxxxx.com"
2014/06/30 12:24:28 [error] 13359#0: *297124 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxxxxxxx, server: www.xxxxxxxx.com, request: "GET /virtual-engineering-simulation-and-optimization HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.xxxxxxxx.com"
```

Comment: You should investigate why php-fpm stops.

Comment: check php error logs, not nginx

Comment: Ok I will check and update you

Comment: [14-Jul-2014 14:18:01] ERROR: epoll: unable to initialize
[14-Jul-2014 14:18:01] ERROR: epoll: unable to initialize
[14-Jul-2014 14:18:01] ERROR: Unable to initialize the event module epoll
[14-Jul-2014 14:18:01] ERROR: Unable to initialize the event module epoll
[14-Jul-2014 14:18:01] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
[14-Jul-2014 14:18:01] ERROR: FPM initialization failed

Comment: i am getting mentioned above error .please help me on this issue.

Comment: Hey did you solve it?